# Dictionary as a generic element of Array

Tags: swift, generics

I have an extension for an Array:

```
extension Array where Element == [String:Double] {
    func values (keyOrder : [String]) -> [[Double]] {
        return self.map { element in
            return (0..<keyOrder.count).compactMap {element[keyOrder[$0]]}
        }
    }
}
```

It works pretty well, but only if Dictionary Key is String and Value is Double. I can imagine this function could work exactly same way for Dictionary of any types, like [AnyHashable:Any] but I have no clue how to define header, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One useful trick you can use in situations like this is to move the `where` clause from the extension declaration to the method declaration. This allows you to introduce new generic placeholders for the nested dictionary's `Key` and `Value` placeholder types:

```
extension Array {
  func nestedValues<Key, Value>(orderedBy keys: [Key]) -> [[Value]] where Element == [Key: Value] {
    return map { element in
      return keys.compactMap { element[$0] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! No one-time used protocol! Kiss!

Answer (score -1):

Use can use value of dictionary **double** as an Any Type. You can try below code.

```
extension Array where Element == [String: Any] {
    func values (keyOrder : [String]) -> [[Any]] {
        return self.map { element in
            return (0..<keyOrder.count).compactMap {element[keyOrder[$0]]}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what to do with Key?

Comment: You can't set key of different type in single Dictionary. You have to explicitly casting keys into String. like int a = 10; dict["\(a)"] = "Set Key as an String from Int".                                                                                                                                        (map["group_id"], TransformOf<String, Int>(fromJSON: { String($0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map { Int($0)! } }))

Comment: I don't understand you. I can have different Dictionaries, key must me hashable. [AnyHashable:Any]. But I don't know is it possible to define them as a type in extension header to use them inside a function to have an output same type as is defined as Element Dictionary value.